# How do I pass data to success template from views with form.cleaned_data.get() in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm building a basic Covid test appointment system. Everything is working fine; I am getting data from users in a form and saving it to database. But I'm trying to show some of that data to the form success page. Like when user enter their details in form such as name, data, time etc after clicking on submit button. I want the name, date, time of the form to render on success page. I even tried this but I'm getting an error like:

> NoReverseMatch at /covid_test
> Reverse for 'success' with arguments '({'name': 'Popes', 'test_date': datetime.date(2021, 4, 23), 'test_time': datetime.time(18, 0)},)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['success$']

Here is the screenshot of the error:

[image]

Below is my code for the same:

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Covid_Test_Model(models.Model):
    gender_chooice = [
        ('Male', 'Male'),
        ('Female', 'Female')
    ]
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    age = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=gender_chooice, default='Male', null=False)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, null=False)
    adhaar_no = models.CharField(max_length=16, null=False)
    address = models.TextField(null=False)
    date = models.DateField(null=False)
    Time = models.TimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=False)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name
```

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

# Create your views here.
from covid_test_app.forms import Covid_Test_Form


def covid_test(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Covid_Test_Form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            name = form.cleaned_data.get("name")
            test_date = form.cleaned_data.get("date")
            test_time = form.cleaned_data.get("Time")
            print(name)
            c = {
                'name': name,
                'test_date': test_date,
                'test_time': test_time
            }
            return redirect('success', c)
    else:
        form = Covid_Test_Form()
        context = {
            'form': form,
        }
    return render(request, 'covid_test.html', context)
```

**Forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import fields
from .models import Covid_Test_Model

class Covid_Test_Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Covid_Test_Model
        fields = ["name", "age", "gender", "phone", "email", "adhaar_no", "address", "date", "Time"]

        widgets = {
            "name": forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            "age": forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'type': 'number'}),
            "gender": forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            "phone": forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'type': 'number'}),
            "email": forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            "adhaar_no": forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            "address": forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'rows': 2}),
            "date": forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            "Time": forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```

**Success.html** This is where I want to show the data of user who filled the form on previous page.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block extrahead %}
    <link href="{% static 'styles/success.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    <div class="container-fluid bg">
  <div class="card-container">
  <div class="bigcard">
    <div class="mx-5 my-5 d-flex flex-column justify-center">
            <h4 class="text-center my-3 display-4 text-info">Success!</h4>
                {# here I am accessing data that I passed as dictionary from my views #}
    <p class="text-center lead">Dear {{ name }} your covid test appointment has been book on {{ test_date }} at {{ test_time }}</p>
      <a type="submit" href="{% url 'home' %}" class="btn btn-info text-white my-4">Back To Home</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Rather than sending the name, date, and time via URL, which is open to misuse/spoofing, you could just set the inserted model ID in a session variable, redirect, then lookup the model from that session variable and display the info.

Comment: @TimNyborg that's something I didn't heard, I'm new to django and web. Would you please share any tutorial or some resources so I can read and implement?

Comment: Django's own documentation is a good place to look, especially re. setting and using session values in views: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-in-views